# How to restructure table (pandas)?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datatable

[image]

I want to use the columns names (emotions) to one column of emotions names,
and concatnate all the rating (values) in one column.

this is my expected table:
[image]

Comment: look at stack() or melt() or pivot().

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = df.melt(id_vars=['Negative Emotion-Mean', 'Negative Emotion-Max', 'participant', 
                   'session', 'block'], var_name='emotion', value_vars=['sadness', 
   'anger', 'interest', 'anxiety', 'shame', 'distress'])
```

Then change the value column name as 'rating'. You try it! I have not written it in my notebook. I hope it will work (may be some minor changes will require). Let me know it works or not.